# In three.js how to position image texture similar to 'contain' in css?

Tags: three.js

My image texture is positioned relative to the center of 3d space instead of  mesh and I don't quite understand what determines its size.
Here is example showing how the same image is positioned on different meshes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VL5SF.jpg

I'd like the image be in the center of the mesh and it's size set similar as 'contain' in css.

The mesh is flat plane created using ShapeBufferGeometry:

```
    const shape = new THREE.Shape( edgePoints );
    const geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( shape );
```

To see any image I have to set:
    `texture.repeat.set(0.001, 0.001);`

Not sure if that matters but after creating the mesh I than set its position and rotation:

```
        mesh.position.copy( position[0] );
        mesh.rotation.set( rotation[0], rotation[1], rotation[2] );
```

I've tried setting those:

```
    mesh.updateMatrixWorld( true );
    mesh.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
    mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    mesh.geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
    mesh.geometry.morphTargetsNeedUpdate = true;
    mesh.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
    mesh.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
    mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    mesh.geometry.tangentsNeedUpdate = true;

    texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

I've played with wrapS / wrapT and offset.

I've checked UV's - I don't yet fully understand this concept but it seems fine. Example of UV for one mesh (I understand those are XY coordinates and they seem to reflect the actual corners of my mesh):

```
    uv: Float32BufferAttribute
      array: Float32Array(8)
        0: -208
        1: 188
        2: 338
        3: 188
        4: 338
        5: 12
        6: -208
        7: 12
```

I've tried setting:

```
                texture.repeat.set(imgHeight/geometryHeight/1000, imgWidth/geometryWidth/1000);
```

Comment: UV coordinates have to be in range 0..1

Comment: _The mesh is flat plane_ Is it a rectangle? Or a free form shape?

Comment: So far it's always a rectangle but I'm considering adding a functionality in the future were it won't be necessarily a rectangle. Altho I'm willing to drop that functionality if it'll fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how `THREE.ShapeGeometry()` computes UV coordinate:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/e622cc7890e86663011d12ec405847baa4068515/src/geometries/ShapeGeometry.js#L157

But you can re-compute them, to put in range `[0..1]`.
Here is an example, click the button to re-compute uvs of the shape geometry:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10);
grid.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.5;
scene.add(grid);

var points = [
  new THREE.Vector2(0, 5),
  new THREE.Vector2(-5, 4),
  new THREE.Vector2(-3, -3),
  new THREE.Vector2(2, -5),
  new THREE.Vector2(5, 0)
];

var shape = new THREE.Shape(points);
var shapeGeom = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry(shape);
var shapeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg")
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(shapeGeom, shapeMat);
scene.add(mesh);

btnRecalc.addEventListener("click", onClick);

var box3 = new THREE.Box3();
var size = new THREE.Vector3();
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(); // for re-use

function onClick(event) {
  
  box3.setFromObject(mesh); // get AABB of the shape mesh
  box3.getSize(size); // get size of that box
  
  var pos = shapeGeom.attributes.position;
  var uv = shapeGeom.attributes.uv;

  for (let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++) {
    v3.fromBufferAttribute(pos, i);
    v3.subVectors(v3, box3.min).divide(size); // cast world uvs to range 0..1
    uv.setXY(i, v3.x, v3.y);
  }

  uv.needsUpdate = true; // set it to true to make changes visible
  
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnRecalc" style="position: absolute;">Re-calculate UVs</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me very very much!